# Creating a custom variation attribute in SFCC

Tags: commerce-cloud

I'm trying to create a custom variation attribute for products in Salesforce Commerce Cloud. There are already attributes like "color", "size", "batteryLife", etc. I want to add a completely new one called "productVariation" or something like that.

I set-up a new sandbox with SFRA, and the default product catalog. If I go to *Merchant Tools >  Products and Catalogs >  Products* then select my product, and open the **variations** tab, there's a section where I can add **shared variation attributes**:

[image: shared variation attributes]

In this case I've already added color, which was a pre-defined variation attribute. It works correctly. If I click **new** the **attribute definition ID** isn't a free-form field:

[image: adding a variation]

After clicking the ellipsis (**...**) the list looks like this:

[image]

There's no option to "create new" there.

**What I've Tried**

I tried going to **Merchant Tools >  Products and Catalogs >  Shared Variation Attributes > Apparel Master Catalog**. But again, if I try to add a new attribute there, it requires me to select from the *same list* of existing variation attributes:

[image: new variation attribute]

I also tried going to **Administration >  Site Development >  Custom Object Types**, and tried to create a new "object type", hoping that might appear in the list of variation attributes, but it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the proper steps you need to display a new Object type attribute need to add a custom property to the product.

Here are the steps:

- go to `Administration >  Site Development >  System Object Types`
- Click on **product** on the list. [image: product]
- Go to **Attribute Definitions** tab [image: tab]
- Select **New**.
- Create the attribute with the desired id and names and Save it.
- Then go to the **Attribute Grouping** tab
- Click **edit** on the **storefrontAttributes** [image: storefrontAttributes]
- Click on the ellipsis to see the list of all product attributes [image: ellipsis]
- Select your newly created attribute, check the select box, then click select.

With that, you will see the new custom attribute on your product, allowing you to use it as a new Object type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can check for attribute Manager and add new attributes there.

> Creating Custom Attributes

To create a custom attribute, follow these steps:

1. In Order Management Administration: click **Settings > Attributes**.
2. From the Attribute Manager, select an attribute group in the list on the left side of the page. The new attribute belongs to the
   selected group. To not assign the attribute to any group, select
   Ungrouped.
3. Enter a name for the **attribute** in the text box above the
   Attribute Group list.
4. Select **Attribute** from the list next to the
   text box.
5. Click **Add**. A new Edit Legacy Attribute Information page
   opens.
6. Edit the various fields on the page as described in Editing
   Custom Attributes.
7. To **save** the new attribute, click **Update**.
   (Clicking Cancel discards changes to the attribute fields, but does
   not delete the attribute itself.)
8. Create the value, such as string,
   dropdown list, number for the Choice Values attribute.

[Refrence Documentation](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FOrderManagement%2FAdministration%2FAdminAttrMgrCustomAttributes.html)

Comment: I can't find "attribute manager" or "order management administration" anywhere in business manager. In the of business manager, I have the menus: Sandbox, Merchant Tools, and Administration. Should there be an additional one for order management?

Comment: Also, are you sure that's the right document? It is under "order management" in the SFCC docs. I'm trying to add a custom attribute that would be available on the **product** itself. I'm just not sure why order management is involved here.